# I'm making a drawing pad that uses Bezier curves. How do I record the past 3 mouse locations when the mouse is down?

Tags: javascript, drawing, bezier

I have it so it records the current mouse position, and the one right before that, and draws a line. I need to also record the 2 previous mouse positions so I can make a 4 point cubic bezier curve. Here is my current code:

```
function penDown (x, y) {
  isPenDown = true;
  localPen.x = x;
  localPen.y = y;
}

// Draws a line if the pen is down.
function penMove (x, y) { 
  if (isPenDown) {
    // Draw the line locally.
    drawLine(localLineColor, localLineThickness, localPen.x, localPen.y, x, y);

    // Move the pen to the end of the line that was just drawn.
    localPen.x = x;
    localPen.y = y;

  }
}

function drawLine (color, thickness, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.lineWidth   = thickness;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1)
  context.lineTo(x2, y2); //THIS line will be removed
  //here needs to be context.bezierCurveTo(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4);. 
  context.stroke();
}
```

This does make the pen actually draw, but it's just a bunch of line segments.

I haven't actually been able to find a javascript drawing pad that draws the bezier curves as you go - I've found some that make the bezier curves, but only after you lift your mouse, like this one - http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Signature-Pad-Plugin-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas/examples/full-window.html

But I'm guessing it's possible to make.

Comment: it's entirely possible, I've written several. But what is your actual question? You've just written a fair bit of story, with code, but we still need something ending with a question mark at the end of it so we can answer that specific thing, instead of guessing what you actually want.

Comment: How do I record the 3 previous mouse locations when the mouse is down?  This question is in the title.

Comment: most of the text you included has nothing to do with that question.

Comment: I figured the question being in the title is clear. The rest is additional information. Also it's basically written again in the first paragraph: " I need to also record the 2 previous mouse positions so I can make a 4 point cubic bezier curve"

Comment: questions on SO are filled with needs and wants, but that doesn't mean the actual post question is going to be "how do I do that thing". How to record mouse clicks, and how to make a 4 point bezier curve, for instance, are *completely* different things.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

Literally record the last three clicks.

```
var ClickRecorder = (function() {
  var Recorder= function(number) {
    this.cap = number;
    this.history = [false, false, false];
  };
  Recorder.prototype = {
    add: function(x,y) {
      while(this.history.length>this.cap) { this.history.splice(0,1); }
      this.history.push({x:x, y:y});
    },
    head: function() { return this.history[0]; },
    tail: function() { return this.history[this.cap-1]; },
    get: function(idx) {
      if(x>=0 && x<this.cap) { return this.history[idx]; }
      return false;
    }
  };
  return Recorder;
}());
```

And instantiate for a 3-click history with

```
var myRecorder = new ClickRecorder(3);
```

Then, whenever you click, add the mouse coordinate to the recorder with `myRecorder.add(mousex, mousey)`. Once you've clicked three times, it's full, and additional clicks will push out the oldest state on each click. Then you can use `myRecorder.get(0)` through `myRecorder.get(2)` to build your curves and update them as you do mouse-coordinate based things.

Note that if you want to live-draw the curves while you click-drag, your last coordinate needs to not be in this list.

Comment: Thanks! So this works for mouse clicks - but it will also record points while the mouse is down and moving?

Comment: no, because that's not what you asked for. Recording the mouse while it's down and moving is just tapping into the mousemove event, nothing fancy or complicated there.